# How to create a uniformly random matrix in Julia?

Tags: matrix, random, julia

l want to get a matrix with uniformly random values sampled from [-1,2]

```
x= rand([-1,2],(3,3))
3x3 Array{Int64,2}:
 -1  -1  -1
  2  -1  -1
 -1  -1  -1
```

but it takes into consideration just -1 and 2, and I'm looking for continuous values for instance -0.9 , 0.75, -0.09, 1.80.
How can I do that?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

for random number in range [a,b]

```
rand() * (b-a) + a
```

and it works for a matrix aswell

```
rand(3,3) * (2 - (-1)) - 1
3x3 Array{Float64,2}:
 1.85611   0.456955   -0.0219579
 1.91196  -0.0352324   0.0296134
 1.63924  -0.567682    0.45602
```

Answer (score 16):

**Note:** I am assuming here that you're looking for uniform random variables.

You can also use the [Distributions](http://distributionsjl.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html) package:

```
## Pkg.add("Distributions") # If you don't already have it installed.
using Distributions
rand(Uniform(-1,2), 3,3)
```

I do quite like isebarn's solution though, as it gets you thinking about the actual properties of the underlying probability distributions.

Comment: but rand(Uniform(0.1,0.3),3,3) doesn't work for real values !!

Comment: @ahmedmazari Could you give more detail?  It seems to work just fine for me.

Comment: randn(Uniform(0.1,0.3),3,3)  !! is it working . have you succeeded to get a normal and uniform distribution between 0.1 and 0.3 ?

Comment: `randn(Uniform()...` should _not_ work, since it is mixing up uniform and random distributions. Use `rand(Uniform(-2,1),3,3)` or `rand(Normal(x,y), 3,3)` to get normally distributed values.

Comment: @ahmedmazari It might be helpful in your case to brush up on some intro stats/probability theory to better understand the context.  Here are a couple Wikipedia articles you might find helpful:  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Probability_distribution **and** https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Normal_distribution **and** https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uniform_distribution_(continuous) **and** https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Discrete_uniform_distribution

Answer (score 5):

You need to use a `FloatRange{Float64}` with the dessired `step`:

```rb
julia> rand(-1.0:0.01:2.0, 3, 3)
3x3 Array{Float64,2}:
 0.79  1.73   0.95
 0.73  1.4   -0.46
 1.42  1.68  -0.55
```

Comment: I should really read the docs for functions, I cant believe I missed that